# Rails - Dynamically switch confirm messages in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, confirm

I am facing this ugly duplication in order to display different confirmation message in my view.

```
<% if current_user.password.nil? and current_user.services.count == 1 %>
  <%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => 'Remove this service will delete your account, are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to remove this authentication option?', :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

I would be pleased to know if there is a way to avoid this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/Users/benoit/rails_projects/website/app/views/services/index.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...e this authentication option?', :method => :delete, :class =...
...                               ^):
    12:         <% for service in @services %>
    13:           <div class="service">
    14:             <%= image_tag "logo_#{service.provider}.png", :class => "left" %>
    15: <%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => current_user.password.nil? and current_user.services.count == 1 ? 'Remove this service will delete your account, are you sure?' : 'Are you sure you want to remove this authentication option?', :method => :delete, :class => "remove" %>
    16: 
    17:             <div class="clear"></div>
    18:           </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just perform a :

```
<%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => current_user.password.nil? and current_user.services.count == 1 ? 'Remove this service will delete your account, are you sure?' : 'Are you sure you want to remove this authentication option?', :method => :delete, :class => "remove" %>
```

Or if you this to be more understandable :

```
<% confirm_message = current_user.password.nil? and current_user.services.count == 1 ? 'Remove this service will delete your account, are you sure?' : 'Are you sure you want to remove this authentication option?' %>

<%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => confirm_message, :method => :delete, :class => "remove" %>
```

I am using Ruby ternary operator, check it : http://invisibleblocks.wordpress.com/2007/06/11/rubys-other-ternary-operator/

Comment: Thank you! However I got this: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'...e this authentication option?', :method => :delete, trying to implement it

Comment: Can you paste the full code with line numbers if possible, and full stack trace ?

Comment: However, try to put the ternary operator into brackets.

Comment: Did my second code proposition (with confirm_message variable) work ?

Comment: In fact I don't know here I have to put the variable, I tried to put it in my model (as CONFIRM_MESSAGE) but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh sorry I made a little mistake. You just have to declare it before the link_to call, I added the tags for erb interpratation. Just retry it with my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! However it returns true or false but I think I can manage that. Merci ;)

Comment: Just add brackets and it will not return true or false anymore ;) De rien, j'suis français aussi Benoît… XD

Answer (score 3):

You could make a helper function:

```
def auth_confirm_delete(current_user)
  if current_user.password.nil? and current_user.services.count == 1
      'Remove this service will delete your account, are you sure?'
  else 
      'Are you sure you want to remove this authentication option?'
  end
end
```

and then it looks better in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Disconnect #{service.provider.capitalize}", service, :confirm => auth_confirm_delete, :method => :delete %>
```